# Query returns null for data from current day to upcoming 7 days

Tags: mysql

I have got this table and data as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE events_calender (
  company_name varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  reg_date varchar(20) 
);

Insert into events_calender values('Childerse Event' , '30-Oct-2015');
Insert into events_calender values('Womens Event' , '05-Nov-2015');
Insert into events_calender values('Mens Event' , '02-Nov-2015');
Insert into events_calender values('DOlls Event' , '02-Oct-2015');
```

I want to return data from current day to upto Upcoming  7 days (Upcoming events)

I have tried it this way

SELECT  * from events_calender
WHERE   reg_date BETWEEN  DATE( NOW() ) AND DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) )

But no data is actually returned even though the records are present

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25bd0/3

Comment: wrong type declared `reg_date varchar(20)` should be `reg_date date`

Comment: Thank you , i cannot change the data type as already lot of data is inserted already to it , so is there anyway  i can modify in the query itself

Comment: **DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) )** must be -7 DAY

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match your description. In your fiddle you have `reg_date timestamp` and the query works accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong type declared `reg_date varchar(20)` should be `reg_date date`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22cfe/1

```
CREATE TABLE events_calender (
  company_name varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  reg_date date 
);

Insert into events_calender values('Childerse Event' , '2015-10-30');
Insert into events_calender values('Womens Event' , '2015-11-05');
Insert into events_calender values('Mens Event' , '2015-11-02');
Insert into events_calender values('DOlls Event' , '2015-10-02');

SELECT * 
FROM events_calender 
WHERE reg_date BETWEEN DATE( NOW() ) AND DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) )
```

Comment: Thanks Alex , but as i mentioned i cannot change the data type , i must chnage in the query only.

Comment: @Preethi Jain: You really should change your table design. It's a very bad idea to store dates as strings as you already notice yourself. When storing dates as strings, especially with month names as you do, be aware of localization issues. '02-Oct-2015' is not a valid date in most languages and would make your str_to_date query fail.